# how to fetch wrong date in a table by SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table as emp, in which one column is hiredate. my hire date column has wrong dates in it. ex: 30-feb-2018, 31-apr-2018,31-jun-2018 etc. 
which means this dates are not exist in those months. how can i find out those wrong dates by sql query.

Comment: Are you also going to fix the root cause of these problems? It is hard to believe, in our times, that you would store hire dates in a column of text data type (such as `varchar2`) and not in the appropriate `date` data type. How did you end up with this situation in the first place?

Comment: i had faced this question in a interview.

Answer (score 1):

Create a small function to test for valid dates:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_Valid_Date(
  datestr VARCHAR2,
  format  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'DD/MM/YYYY'
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
AS
  x DATE;
BEGIN
  IF datestr IS NULL THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  x := TO_DATE( datestr, format );
  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
/
```

Then call it in your query:

```
SELECT hiredate
FROM   emp
WHERE  is_Valid_Date( hiredate, 'DD-MON-YYYY' ) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 12.2 and above, the validation could be easily implemented using the 
`DEFAULT .. ON CONVERSION ERROR` option of `TO_DATE`

```
SQL> with t(hiredate)
  2  AS
  3  (
  4  select '28-feb-2018' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  select '30-feb-2018' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  select '31-apr-2018' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7  select '31-jun-2018' FROM DUAL
  8  )
  9  SELECT hiredate
    ,TO_DATE(hiredate DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR
        ,'DD-MON-YYYY') valid_date
FROM t;

HIREDATE    VALID_DATE
----------- ---------
28-feb-2018 28-FEB-18
30-feb-2018 NULL
31-apr-2018 NULL
31-jun-2018 NULL
```